# How to convert V24 drawables to something lower that is compatible with older APIs

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable

I have noticed that some of my drawables say v24 (some are JPGs and some are PNGs). This wasn't an issue until I started testing on older APIs. My lowest compatibility I'm shooting for is API 23, but v24 isn't supported and my app keeps crashing.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Viewing the project as "Android" will hide drawable v24 folder. View the project as "Project Files" and you can navigate to both drawable and drawable v24 folders. From here click and drag your drawables to drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks you actually saved my life

Comment: Glad I could help, I totally forgot about this post :) Happy it's still helping others @princebillyGK